# switch 'expected declaration' error even when i have declared in Swift, Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, switch-statement, declaration, xcode6.1

I get an error saying "expected declaration" by the switch statement
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cjeo3sxg0zw431/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-30%20at%2001.01.48.png?dl=0

```
let questionSelected = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))


switch questionSelected{
case 0:
let x = "(question goes here)"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cases must be exhaustive otherwise you must have a default statement.  I modified the case 0: just to get it to execute in a playground.

```
let questionSelected = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))


switch questionSelected{
case 0:
    let x = "(question goes here)"
default:
    break
}
```

Okay, went an extra step.  This works.  Hook up the label to a storyboard.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var questionBox: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let questionSelected = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

        switch questionSelected{
        case 0:
            questionBox.text = "Does this work?"
        default:
            questionBox.text = "Does this work better?"
        }

    }
}
```

Second update:

```
func thisCodeMustBeInAFunction() {

     let questionSelected = Int(arc4random_uniform(1))

     switch questionSelected{
         case 1:
             questionBox.text = "(question goes here)"
         default:
             break
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply however that wasn't the problem. The problem is that when I type in "switch" and then the declaration it doesn't register the declaration for some reason. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cjeo3sxg0zw431/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-30%20at%2001.01.48.png?dl=0

Comment: Updated with more code.  Let me know if we are getting closer.

Comment: I've updated it with the entire view controller and screenshots of  my story board are here if thats helpful! I'm new to this so my code is probably not the simplest way of doing everything! https://www.dropbox.com/s/spdvnl6qo9z3tfs/Screen%20Shot%202014-10-30%20at%2001.23.12.png?dl=0

Comment: added more, but you have control statements and math occurring outside a method.

Comment: thanks you very much...I hadn't realised that the switch had to be contained within a function

Answer (score -1):

check the 'questionSelected' variable scope and Switch statement scope are in the same level